# Twitter bootstrap affix issue

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been trying to implement and use the `affix` feature of Bootstrap but, the container sticks below and sort of jams when I scroll.

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/75rrwe1n/

I wanted to implement the affix as the Twitter Home Page (https://www.twitter.com) without the signed-in state.

Comment: but in your fiddle , container is actually moving when it is scrolled. Don't u want this effect?

Comment: @VivekSolanki: I wanted the  container to move when scrolled and move behind the jumbotron above. Everything till the jumbotron should remain as top and fixed. I achieved this by providing a margin-top to the container and playing with z-index

Comment: that's good, you got your solution :)